# Save Selected Row in UITableView To NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to save the selected state of a row so that when the tableview loads the selected row's corresponding checkmark appears. I've tried this method below in viewDidAppear but it's not working.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

super.viewDidAppear(true)
let checkMarkToDisplay = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("lastSelection") as! Int
lastSelection = NSIndexPath(forRow: checkMarkToDisplay, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastSelection)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

}

var lastSelection: NSIndexPath!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if self.lastSelection != nil
{

    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.lastSelection)?.accessoryType = .None
}

if indexPath.row > 0
{
    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    self.lastSelection = indexPath

    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}      

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(indexPath.row, forKey: "lastSelection")
```

Comment: Perform this checking in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method instead of `viewWillAppear`. Put a checking condition on it `if(indexPath.row==NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("lastSelection") as! Int)`. And then set the accessory type

Comment: During viewDidAppear, there is no knowing that target cell has been even created yet. You must perform your cell customization operations inside your tableView delegate methods

Comment: ah makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement your logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath and remove your checkmark code from viewDidAppear.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let checkMarkToDisplay  =   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("lastSelection") as! Int

    if checkMarkToDisplay == indexPath.row{
        cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    else{
        cell?.accessoryType = .None
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does he have to create indexPath if he is already in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Just check if indexPath.row is equal to your checkMarkToDisplay and then set the accessory checkmark. No need to create indexpath or to call cellForRowAtIndexPath method  when you are already in there

Comment: @NSNoob Yes i have implemented according to him, same like as he want.

Comment: Okay great. It would be helpful if you explained what he is doing wrong with his code. I have left a comment but people are most likely to read the answer.

Comment: Exactly thats the reason and we can't put lots of line on comment box.

Comment: Thanks I've changed my conditions for indexPath.row and it works now. Also I am a her :)

Comment: @DaisyR. Ohh sorry for he, Its She :)

Answer (score 0):

Move this to viewDidLoad()

```
lastSelection = NSIndexPath(forRow: checkMarkToDisplay, inSection: 0)
```

and delete this

```
self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(lastSelection)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
```

Then add this to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //create the cell
    //then
    cell.accessoryType = lastSelection == indexPath ? .Checkmark : .None

    //other cell configuration

    return cell
}
```